# dynamic query to pass email field value

Tags: dynamic-soql

How to frame the below dynamic query. Opportunity_User__c field has value in format of "test@gmail.com". Now i want to retrieve all the opportunities having that value using dynamic query.

```
List<Opportunity> opplist = new List<Opportunity>();  
String Query='SELECT id FROM opportunity Where Opportunity_User__c=\'test@gmail.com\'';
opplist = database.query(Query);
```

I am getting the below error : "System.QueryException: unexpected token: '@'"

Comment: Is it the entire query? I don't see any prob in that...I have ran the below query in developer console and i didn't get any syntax error 


List<Opportunity> opplist = new List<Opportunity>();  
String Query='SELECT id FROM opportunity Where Opportunity_User__c=\'test@gmail.com\'';
opplist = database.query(Query);

Comment: yes same here ..I dont see any problem ..

Comment: Yes the error was not coming now but i can see the records in my system with that value but the records returned was zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you try get all emails called 'test' - then try this:

```
String Query='SELECT id FROM opportunity Where Opportunity_User__c LIKE \'test%\'';
```

Or this to be more specific:

```
String Query='SELECT id FROM opportunity Where Opportunity_User__c LIKE \'test_gmail.com\'';
```